# Alter SVG After Highcharts is Redrawn

Tags: svg, highcharts

I'm trying to specifically target the first and last x-axis labels, which are *text* elements, and alter their attributes.

To preface this issue, I was trying to keep the first and last x-axis labels within the confines of the Highcharts container. Unfortunately, they are cutting off in the UI.

[image: Highcharts X-Axis Label UI Bug]

This is my configuration:

```
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            showFirstLabel: true, 
            showLastLabel: true, 
            labels: { 
                step: 3,
            formatter: function(){
                return options.labels[this.value];
            },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                    color: '#9c9c9c'
                },
                // x: 5,
                y: 10
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            // lineColor: 'transparent',
            tickLength: 0,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0
        }],
```

The `step` key is causing this I realize. Otherwise, I would be able to use `overflow:justify`, but I wanted the step. So, I then decided that perhaps altering the SVG would be a good solution. It worked when the chart is first loaded, but it does not work when being redrawn.

This was my solution on 'load', which I'd like to replicate on 'redraw':

```
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function(chart){
    $('.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').first().attr('x', 25);
    $('.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').last().attr('x', 813);
});
```

Comment: Callback function is execute when the chart object is finished loading and rendering. Its not called on chart redraw. Refer this one : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.Chart

Answer (score 2):

You should configure [these](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) [callbacks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) in the options of your chart.  It's cleaner that way:

```
function moveLabels(){
    $('.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').first().attr('x', 25);
    $('.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').last().attr('x', 813);
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: moveLabels
            redraw: moveLabels
           }
        }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work. When I console log the 'x' attribute within the moveLabels function, it has certainly changed. But, at the same time, I can visibly see the y-axis labels (first and last) rubberband as if the 'x' attribute is reverting to '10' for the first and '765.0769230769231' for the last label when I 'redraw'. To reiterate after this change has been implemented, 'load' is working perfectly.

Comment: @ConAntonakos, can you code up an example jsFiddle or Plnkr?